# Is it possible to use the File JavaScript api to load a server side file?

Tags: javascript, html, file, io

A quick question, I recently checked out the new html5 File api for javascript. See it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications). Is it possible to use it to pull in a server side file without ajax? I know there's a File object in JavaScript, could I do a "new File("serverSideStuff.xml");" with that?

Comment: What is so bad about AJAX? If the resource is external, it stands to reason that you will need to make a network-bound request to get it; the File api could encapsulate it, but in the end, it would be the exact same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [API description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications)  -

> Using the File API added to the DOM in HTML5, it's now possible for
>   web content to ask the user to **select local files**, then read the
>   contents of those files.

So no, you can't select server side files

Comment: That's sad, it seems like a nice unified way to load files. Someone should propose it for server side files. thanks

Answer (score 0):

*No, it is only for local files, as I know.*

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because the user must be aware of what your are loading, and is the user who can tell you what you can load or not.

Comment: But I'm not talking about loading user files or local files, I'm talking about files on the server the website is running on. Would that be possible?

Comment: As far as I know, FileAPI only can read files that user explicity opened by it self, using drag'n'drop or <input type='file'/> tag.

Comment: @G1i1ch, you can use ajax to load files from server. But that is not FileAPI. FileAPI is for local filesystem only.